# find out the mousemovement direction

Tags: javascript, mousemove

I have a function that gets called for `touchmove` and I need to find out the direction of the mouse movement. Requested values are "left" and "right". How can I do this without using any plugins??

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove',
    function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
        if(direction == 'left'){
            my.MouseWheel.handle(-1);
        } else if (direction == 'right'){
            my.MouseWheel.handle(1);
        }   
    });
```

Comment: You have to save the pointer position on `touchstart`, then compare inside `touchmove`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the touchstart event, then get the coordinates of the touch using pageX and pageY. then on the touchmove event get the coordinates again and compare to the previous to find the direction.

```
var mouse_x;
var mouse_y;
function load(){
     document.addEventListener('touchstart',get_mouse_coords,false);
     document.addEventListener('touchmove',check_swipe,false);
}

function get_mouse_coords(e){
    mouse_x = e.pageX;
    mouse_y = e.pageY;

}
function check_swipe(e){
    var new_mouse_x = e.pageX;
    if ((new_mouse_x - mouse_x) > 75){
        //swiped right
    }else if ((new_mouse_x - mouse_x) < -75){
        //swiped left
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `output`, where does it come from?

Comment: @Optox what function i should call??

Comment: @Zim84, output was left over from some code i copied. @simmi simmi, what do you mean which function? You add both of the listeners and then the two functions get_mouse_coords and check_swiped will check the coordinates of the touch and the calculate the direction (left or right). Add your code ` my.MouseWheel.handle(-1);` where I left the swipe left and swipe right comments.